# Incompatible types при использовании getFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction

Имеется участок кода:

```
package asus.example.com.notes1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private void selectItem(int position){
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (position){
            case 1:
                fragment = new PizzaFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new PastaFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new StoresFragment();
                break;
                default:
                    fragment = new TopFragment();
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Android Studio почему-то подчеркивает строку `FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();` и пишет

```
> Incompatible types. Required:
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction Found:
> android.app.FragmentTransaction
```

Пробовал импортировать и заменить

```
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
```

на

```
> android.app.FragmentTransaction
```

Однако тогда подчеркивает другую строку: `ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);` и пишет

```
> Wrong 2nd arguement type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: А так же наследовать активность от `AppCompatActivity` и использовать тему из семейства `AppCompat`, чтобы всё это заработало.

Comment: @lkibana, этот метод почему-то не находит вообще, хотя и сам пользовался им уже. Возможно из-за наследования от Activity, но менять не буду, потому что если поставить AppCompat, то тема будет несовместима вроде